# cumcount based on certain values sorted by date in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the a dataframe `df` that looks like sorted by `ID` and `Date` in ascending and descending order respectively:

```
    ID  Date        Place
0   1   2021-04-28  1
1   1   2021-02-28  2
2   1   2020-12-23  11
3   1   2020-11-29  1
4   2   2021-07-07  1
5   2   2021-06-20  4
6   2   2021-05-26  8
7   2   2021-04-08  1
8   2   2021-03-03  3
9   2   2021-02-03  1
10  2   2021-01-13  9
11  2   2020-12-23  12
12  3   2021-06-02  1
13  3   2021-05-08  1
14  3   2021-04-08  9
15  3   2021-01-17  1
16  3   2020-12-23  4
17  3   2020-12-02  1
18  3   2020-11-14  2
```

I would like to add two new columns called `Number of 1` which is defined to be cumulative count of number 1 occurred in `Place` for each `ID` and another column called `Recent Number of 1` which is defined to be the `cumcount` of 1's in Place but the count restarts every year.
So the outcome looks like

```
    ID  Date        Place  Number of 1  Recent Number of 1
0   1   2021-04-28  1      2            1
1   1   2021-02-28  2      1            0            
2   1   2020-12-23  11     1            1
3   1   2020-11-29  1      1            1
4   2   2021-07-07  1      3            3
5   2   2021-06-20  4      2            2
6   2   2021-05-26  8      2            2
7   2   2021-04-08  1      2            2
8   2   2021-03-03  3      1            1
9   2   2021-02-03  1      1            1
10  2   2021-01-13  9      0            0
11  2   2020-12-23  12     0            0
12  3   2021-06-02  1      4            2
13  3   2021-05-08  1      3            1
14  3   2021-04-08  9      2            1
15  3   2021-01-17  1      2            1
16  3   2020-12-23  4      1            1
17  3   2020-12-02  1      1            1
18  3   2020-11-14  2      0            0
```

I think for the recent number it should have something to do with

`df.sort_values(by = ['ID', 'Date'], ascending = [True, False], inplace = True)`

`df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.year`

`df.groupby(['ID','Date']).cumcount` something
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: How is `Number of 1` calculated? Also, for index 6, where place = 8, why is it 2? **The outcome `Place` is different from your input**

Comment: the first table do not match the expected result table.

Comment: Hi Naveed, sorry updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

the result don't match the expected outcome, as the first table in question don't match the table under expected.

The below is from the first table in the question

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['number of 1']=df.sort_values(['ID','Date'],ascending=[1,1])['Place'].eq(1).groupby(df['ID']).cumsum()

df['Recent number of 1']=df.sort_values(['ID','Date'],ascending=[1,1])['Place'].eq(1).groupby([df['ID'],df['Date'].dt.year]).cumsum()
df
```

```
    ID  Date    Place   number of 1     Recent number of 1
0   1   2021-04-28  8   2   1
1   1   2021-02-28  1   2   1
2   1   2020-12-23  11  1   1
3   1   2020-11-29  1   1   1
4   2   2021-07-07  1   3   3
5   2   2021-06-20  4   2   2
6   2   2021-05-26  8   2   2
7   2   2021-04-08  1   2   2
8   2   2021-03-03  3   1   1
9   2   2021-02-03  1   1   1
10  2   2021-01-13  9   0   0
11  2   2020-12-23  12  0   0
12  3   2021-06-02  1   3   2
13  3   2021-05-08  8   2   1
14  3   2021-04-08  9   2   1
15  3   2021-01-17  1   2   1
16  3   2020-12-23  4   1   1
17  3   2020-12-02  7   1   1
18  3   2020-11-14  1   1   1
```